# Using count in triggers to update another table

Tags: mysql, trigger, count

Say i have a table called `trx_request` with the following data

```
id | confirmed(TIME) | finished(TIME)
-------------------------------------
1  | 12:05:00        | NULL
2  | 13:11:00        | NULL
```

and another table called `trx_updates` with the following data

```
request(FK) | role(INT) | added(TIME)
------------------------------------------
1           | 1         | 14:02:00
```

I'd like to make a trigger that after a record is inserted into `trx_updates`, counts how many records has the same value in the `request` field (such as how many '1's there are). And then, does a check to see if the count reaches 4 ('1' shows up 4 times). When it does, it updates the `trx_requests.finished` to NOW().

How would one make a count statement in triggers? or are triggers the way to go?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This trigger does the job:

```
create trigger trx_updates_atrig
after insert on trx_updates for each row begin
DECLARE updatecount INT;
  set updatecount = ( select count(*) from trx_updates where request = new.request );
  if updatecount=4
    then
      update trx_request set finished=NOW() where id = new.request;
  end if;
end//
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8e31/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Phil, I can clearly understand your answer, but somehow I keep getting `SQL Error (1109): Unknown table 'trx_request' in field list` right after I insert the fourth record. Do you have any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Is trx_request the correct table name to update? Is it in the same database (if not, it will need fully qualifying with the DB name)? Do you have permission to update it?

Comment: Oh, I see it is called trx_request in one part of the question and trx_requests in another. That is probably the problem. Learn to troubleshoot? :P

Comment: Oh my, that IS the problem. My bad :) Thanks heaps