# SQLite: Using count in triggers to update another column

Tags: trigger, update, sqlite, computed-column, generated-columns

UPDATE: Fixed. Not 100% sure why sqlfiddle.com didn't like my syntax, but using https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 worked. I did change the last `WHERE` clause to be based on the `id` column, so that it only updates the current record, and increments instead of storing max() on records for `username`.

I'm trying and failing to do something similar as described here (but in SQLite):
[Using count in triggers to update another table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57657/using-count-in-triggers-to-update-another-table).

I assume a trigger is the best way to achieve what I want, but am open to alternate suggestions. My SQL experience is... limited, to say the least.

My goal is to have one column with an identifier, say `username` and another column that is a count of the times `username` is in the database at the time of the record insertion.

```
id | username | u_cnt | etc
1  |  MarkC   |   0   | ...
2  |  PeterB  |   0   | ...
3  |  MarkC   |   1   | ...
```

Here's a sample of what I've been trying:

```
create trigger count_user
after insert on rec_info
begin
  update rec_info set u_cnt = ( select count(*) from rec_info where username = new.username );
end
```

I've been bashing my head against the docs at https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#syntax_restrictions_on_update_delete_and_insert_statements_within_triggers
but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the `count_user` statement. Depending on where I'm testing it I'll get one of the following
`near ")": syntax error` or `could not prepare statement (1 incomplete input)`, neither of which are that useful to me.

I've also tried making `u_cnt` a generated/computed column ( https://sqlite.org/gencol.html ), but trying to declare the column with:

```
u_cnt int as (count(username)) stored,
```

Which gives me `misuse of aggregate function count()` and trying to add `HAVING` or `GROUP BY` led me down a rabbit hole that gave me and headache and didn't seem to lead to progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error i can't reproduce, but i think you want this for your trigger.

`MAX(u_cnt) + 1` can also be used as long as the insert only uses `0` for `u_cnt`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE rec_info 
>     ("id" INTEGER, "username" TEXT(6), "u_cnt" TEXT(6))
> ;
> ```

> ```
> create trigger count_user
> after insert on rec_info
> begin
>   update rec_info 
>       set u_cnt = ( select COUNT(*) from rec_info  where username = new.username) 
>   WHERE username = new.username;
> end
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO rec_info 
>     ("id", "username", "u_cnt")
> VALUES
>     (1, 'MarkC', '0')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO rec_info 
>     ("id", "username", "u_cnt")
> VALUES
>     (2, 'PeterB', '0')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO rec_info 
>     ("id", "username", "u_cnt")
> VALUES
>     (3, 'MarkC', '0')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO rec_info 
>     ("id", "username", "u_cnt")
> VALUES
>     (4, 'MarkC', '0')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM rec_info
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | u_cnt
> -: | :------- | :----
>  1 | MarkC    | 3    
>  2 | PeterB   | 1    
>  3 | MarkC    | 3    
>  4 | MarkC    | 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7c2642e52603493cfaa503c6597180ef)*